# jquery mobile scroller only works once

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

Using http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/

After click on Set or Cancel it leaves the field on blur not allowing to launch again.  If I choose another field, then this one again it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/datepicker/jquery.scroller-1.0.1.min.css">
<script src="/public/datepicker/jquery.scroller-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    $('.date').scroller({
        startYear : currentYear - 70,
        endYear : currentYear - 18
    });     
});
</script>
```

Field is:

```
<div id="inputField">
<input type="text" name="person[dob]" class="textEntry date" value="<%= @person.dob %>" "<%= placeholder( 'Your Birthday - 1/1/1900' ) %>" />   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, this problem occurs only with jQuery Mobile beta 1. But a fix is provided with mobiscroll-1.0.2. Give it a try
http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/downloads/detail?name=mobiscroll-1.0.2.zip